# python Pandas append multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've read many solutions on my question but any of them work for me.
I've a first df like:

| col1 | col2 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | d1 |

A 2nd df like:

| col2 | col3 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b2 | c2 | e2 |

and I want :

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 |  | d1 |  |
|  | b2 | c2 |  | e2 |

Every solution I read did not work for me.

SOLUTION:
I used

> df = pandas.concat([df1, df2])

my error was due to post-processing

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and using the sort argument.

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':['a1'],'col2':['b1'],'col4':['d1']})

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col2':['b2'],'col3':['c2'],'col5':['e2']})

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=True)
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0   a1   b1  NaN   d1  NaN
0  NaN   b2   c2  NaN   e2
```